# Sci-fi story where society uses bracelets to denote hierarchy

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to identify a story I read long ago, probably in 70-80's but likely was from golden age SF. I think it was a novel.

What I remember was that:

- There was an alien invasion, but I think that the main invasion fleet was on its way to earth, it hadn't happened yet
- There was something about the aliens were actually (secretly?) insectoid, I remember for sure that they had ovipositors
- On Earth, people wore gold? bracelets, one feature of is that it denoted who your superior was. But it was more than this: there was something about how a person had to obey any command from a superior. This may have been part of the alien's secret plan to gain control when they arrive. I mean, I don't remember if it was known to everyone that the bracelets could do this.
- The bracelet's use and hierarchy feature was the major plot point at the end:

> A human on Earth manages to gain the highest level of control, even above the aliens. Kind of like the ending of Niven & Pournelle's *Footfall*.

I thought that this was a novel by A. E. van Vogt, but when I search his bibliography, I can't find a match.

Comment: Could this be one of the Julian May '*Saga of the Exiles*' books? Golden Torcs give aliens control over silver torcs, etc

Comment: Nope. I have every book in the Saga of the Pliocene Exile, plus the entire Galactic Milieu series. This is something different. But the Saga is great!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this might be [Dr. Orpheus](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3064813-dr-orpheus) by Ian Wallace. This was published in 1969 and it's the second in a series of books Wallace wrote featuring the character *Croyd*.

[image: Dr Orpheus]

> Dr Orpheus finds a future Earthworld caught in a double-destructive pincers between benign enslavement by the miracle drug Anagonon and hideous enslavement by invaders from a far galaxy. To meet this twofold threat, Croyd must exercise his amazing abilities to the fullest, resorting to time travel, mind transfers, and a breathtakingly swift shell game of body transpositions, all the while battling the greatest odds he has ever faced.

As I recall Ian Wallace's *Croyd* books are all a bit weird even for 1969. The protagonist *Croyd* is some kind of advanced human who can travel in time and occupy different bodies. There is an invasion fleet from the *Mandomen Galaxy*, though as you say it hasn't reached Earth yet, and the ovipositor bearing aliens are the *Myrons*:

> The masculate Myrons of Mandomen Galaxy were a breed that Mandomen mammals found peculiar, although an intelligent insect on Earth (if any had evolved) would merely have found them normal in a different way. Myrons, who were not insects but decapods, had by birth three sexes: male, female, and masculate. The females were the brooders, the mystique centers of clans, the rulers: queens and princesses. The males were the fertilizers, rather stupid, strong in only one respect and otherwise weak.

The bracelets behave as you say, and the invaders plan to seize *Bracelet One*, which controls all the others. Croyd defeats the invasion by obtaining *Bracelet Zero*:

> “Perfectly. But now tell me about Zero.”
>
> “About Zero?”
> The German sat up straight. The gynecologist was frowning, puzzled. The other seven merely continued their attitudes of intense involvement.
>
> “Yes,” Croyd insisted. “What about Zero in the Pythagorean arithmetic?”
>
> Beginning to tremble again, the guilt-ridden psychiatrist ventured: “Zero did not appear in the Pythagorean arithmetic.”
>
> “Why not?”
>
> “Because Zero was not known until it was introduced into the algebra by Arabic philosophers nearly fifteen hundred years later—”
>
> “And if Pythagoras had comprehended the number Zero—what rank would he have assigned it?”
>
> The silence was intellectually and emotionally loaded.
>
> The German internist fired a reply like a machine gun volley. “The question should be put a bit differently. If Pythagoras had lived today, and if in the light of all our knowledge he had projected his mystical system, which he might well have done: then how would he have ranked the number Zero? I say he would have recognized Zero as the number of psi-space, the number of ancient Egyptian Nun, the formless male-female progenitor of all the gods: the root of our word non. Pythagoras would have accorded Zero a rank higher than One, higher than Alpha—the ultimate rank, with no higher rank possible!”
>
> That was when Croyd exhibited his bracelet.

Comment: I'm sure _Dr. Orpheus_ is it, thanks! 

I don't see it in my collection, I must have read it from the library.